# Facebook like status update in rails 2.1.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

Facebook like status update of CRUD operation in rails 2.1.0 over different model like Comments, Posts and Reviews over product.

If there is any gem already Available for this purpose or you can suggest me best solution of it. Inshort **Activity Update of whole Application**

Answer (score 0):

I think this question would be better suited in the Ruby/Ruby-on-Rails group(s):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails-2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby